# How to return sampled indexes using PROC SURVEYSELECT in SAS?

Tags: sas

I would like to simulate 1000 samples from my original data set using PROC SURVEYSELECT. I don't want SAS to output 1000 sampled data sets because it would take up a lot of space. How do I create 1000 indicator variables and attach them to my original data set? Each of these indicator variables will have a value of 1 if my observation is selected in the replicate, and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical paper on this is David Cassell's [Don't be Loopy](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf).

The basic core is this statement:

```
proc surveyselect data=YourData out=outboot /* 1 */
 seed=30459584 /* 2 */
 method=urs /* 3 */
 samprate=1 /* 4 */
 outhits /* 5 */
 rep=1000; /* 6 */
 run;
```

where `outhits` will generate a new record for each sampled row (if it's sampled 2 or more times, it will become 2 or more records), and a variable `REPLICATE` will be created that will store the replicate number.

It only creates one variable (with values 1-1000), but that's normally desirable: you can then run the analysis with `BY REPLICATE;` and get your results.

If you need to turn it into 1000 variables/one row per ID, you can have a data step after the `SurveySelect` and use an array:

```
data want;
  set outboot;
  by [id-variable];
  array rep[1000];
  retain rep1-rep1000;
  rep[replicate]=1;
  if last.[id-variable] then do;
    output;
    call missing(of rep[*]);
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for the most helpful comment. When I use rep=1000 in proc surveyselect, my output data set contains of all 1000 replicated samples concatenated together. What happens if I want to do multi-stage sampling from each of these replicates? Proc surveyselect doesn't allow BY replicate statement, but maybe I can use STRATA replicate instead? I thank you so much for your response again.

Comment: @YooSam Yes, STRATA is effectively a BY statement in SURVEYSELECT, though I am not a statistician and couldn't tell you if there are any other concerns related to the differences.  I _think_ the results are identical between STRATA sampling and sampling 1000 separate tables.